# Are there any other good graphical administration tools for SQLite on the mac, instead of the Firefox Extension?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, administration

Are there any other good graphical administration tools for SQLlite on the mac, instead of the Firefox Extension?

Comment: not Dupe since the OP is asking about something that is not the Firefox plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools

- [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/)
- [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/)
- [SQLiteManager](http://sqlabs.net/)
- [SyBrowser](http://www.macsos.com.au/)

Answer (score 3):

I use this [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/development.html) it works fine, is lightweight and free (as in beer). And no complaints about it at all, however its not actively maintained anymore, which is a pity. But the code is free (as in speech) and it also can be used on Windows and Linux.

Comment: I've also used this for my projects.  The UI is a little clunky (QT instead of native Cocoa), but it has a lot of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Java and JDBC setups you could use [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) together with a SQLite JDBC Driver [E.g.](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC)

I've used Squirrel for a while now and its pretty good.